# T-SQL, why do we write GO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Why are there two GO's here in this code? When the query only has to run once why do we need to include it?

```
USE AdventureWorks2016;
GO

SELECT 
    Ord.SalesOrderID, Ord.OrderDate,
    (SELECT MAX(OrdDet.UnitPrice)
     FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS OrdDet
     WHERE Ord.SalesOrderID = OrdDet.SalesOrderID) AS MaxUnitPrice
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Ord;
GO
```

Comment: `GO` isn't a T-SQL keyword, it's used by IDEs, such as SSMS, as a batch separator. Some commands must be the only statement in a batch (such as the creation of an SP). This allows you to run multiple batches one after the other with ease. It would also clear things like variables, which only persist for the batch they are declared in.

Comment: [SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu: okay, what do you mean by batch separator? SomI can see the code chunk ends?

Comment: No, that's a statement terminator (`;`).

Comment: @Larnu: okay thanks but still a little confused because I don't understand what you mean by batch...

Comment: Batch means what it implies, a [Batch of SQL Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/batches-of-sql-statements?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: In some case a `GO` batch separator is required, such as `CREATE VIEW`, which must be the only statement in the batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, GO isolates each batch

For example

```
Declare @v int = 25
Select @V;

go

Select @v ;
```

The 1st SELECT executes fine and returns 25 while the 2nd throws an error

Comment: Why does it throw an error? Because the variable is gone? So usually or mostly we include GO after ;?

Comment: @David Think of it as (at)v is now out-of-scope after the GO